# What is happening with the UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter?

Tags: community

Being a big fan of the UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter, I'd like to know why it is not published regularly anymore.  The last issue dates back to mid-January. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

According to [this message](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-news-team/2010-November/001200.html) the former editor had to step down due to personal issues, and that has caused the delays in the last few issues.

If you are interested, you can see how to get involved at http://princessleia.com/journal/?p=3883